# protractor deprecated getLocationAbsUr

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, protractor

I am trying to write a code for tasting that I'm redirected to the index.html file using protractor .When I type in terminal  protractor protractor.conf.js to execute the e2e tests. it shows me this error :

> W/protractor - `browser.getLocationAbsUrl()` is deprecated, please use  `browser.getCurrentUrl` instead.

Why is that happening?Isn't getLocationAbsUrl Protractor's words?

the code for Configuring Protractor

```
exports.config = {
   allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
   specs: [
     'e2e/*.js'
      ],
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },

 baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/',

 framework: 'jasmine',
 directConnect: true,

 jasmineNodeOpts: {
  defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
}
};
```

Code for e2e test

```
'use strict';

describe('conFusion App E2E Testing', function() {

   it('should automatically redirect to / when location hash/fragment is empty', function() {

   browser.get('index.html');
   expect(browser.getLocationAbsUrl()).toMatch("/");

});
```

Comment: `expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toMatch("/");` Use this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your error said, this function is `deprecated`. It means the use of this code is now discouraged. You should use `getCurrentUrl()`.

From [Protractor's Github](https://github.com/angular/protractor/pull/3969/files):

> `browser.getLocationAbsUrl()` is now deprecated, you should use 
>   `browser.getCurrentUrl()` instead.